# My asp.net page cause scroll up.. only in case of Firefox

Tags: asp.net, html, firefox, scroll

In my ASP.net page, which does have scroll bar, I have placed a customized control in which I have used a HTML check box (it's like hierarchical structure).

When I scroll down the page (to reach to that control) and then I select any item from that check box, the page scrolls up to the top of the page, without causing post back.

How can I stop the scrolling issue from happening?

Note: It only happens with Firefox, it doesn't happens on other browsers i.e IE 8/9 & Chrome.

This is my customized control, which I have used in My another asp.net page,is when i check any of the bellow items. it causes scroll up of page.

```
<asp:Panel ID="TreeViewPanel" runat="server" style="border: 1px solid #CCC; width: 210px; padding:5px 0;">
<ul id="tree">
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="treeHdrCheck1" runat="server"/>Win Exe
    </label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" runat="server"/>.EXE</label></li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" runat="server"/>.DLL</label></li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" runat="server"/>.OCX</label></li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="4" runat="server"/>.SYS</label></li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="5" runat="server"/>.SCR</label></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: What have you done? That is, post your code that you have attempted so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Can you create a HTML page based on the generated html result? Please create a live demo also if possible. e.g. using jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you styling your checkboxes?

If you use CSS like

```
label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

label input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
    top: -10000px;
}
```

to hide the actual input element from the containing label, then you may need to remove the `top: -10000px;` part, because Firefox seems to be wanting to scroll the input element into view.